# Requested registry access is not allowed. (mscorlib) -- SQL Server 2014 Upgrade advisor issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

While running the SQL Server 2014 upgrade advisor against a remote SQL Server 2005, this error shows up:

> Could not populate SQL Instances: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed

It's able to connect to the SQL Server 2005 database and its also populating all the required databases, but when I'm tring to click `Run` at the last step this error occurs.

I even installed the SQL Server 2012 upgrade advisor in my system and tried to run it against the same SQL Server 2005 database but getting the same error.

However if I use the SQL Server 2008 upgrade advisor and connect to SQL Server 2005 I'm not getting any error. The tool is generating successfully all the Pre and Post upgrade issues.

Please help me in identifying the issue. I'm running the tool with Run as administrator option.

Comment: Hi all, can any body help with above issue..

Comment: Don't know if UA2012 supports analyzing 2005 DBs but a couple of things to look into for the problem you encountered. First make sure you're running the same platform (x64 or x86) as your SQL Server. The account you logged in with to run UA needs to be in the sysadmin role of the instance you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the details.About platform im sure its using same x64 but i need to check about sysadmin role in the db for which im running the UA.I have the necessary admin rights on the system.